# Problema com função javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

To tendo um problema de "Uncaught ReferenceError: nameValue is not defined", sendo que o "nameValue", está sendo passado pra função, to sem ideia de qual o problema.

function :

```
 function cleanStorage(type, namevalue){
        console.log(nameValue)
        if(type == 'storage'){
            localStorage.clear();
            return [1, 'Sucesso ao limpar storage!']
        }

    if(type == 'item'){

        if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty(nameValue)) {
            return [0, "Erro. Item a ser exluido não exite!"];
        }

        localStorage.removeItem(namevalue);

        return [1,'Sucesso ao exluir item!']
    }

    return [0, 'Erro. parametro passado é invalido'];


}
```

Minha chamada:

```
cleanStorage('item','teste')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é a grafia do nome do parâmetro, na função você declarou como "namevalue", mas, em alguns lugares da função você usou "nameValue". Tem que padronizar todas as chamadas para "namevalue"

Comment: Mano bgd, e olhei umas 100 vezes e não tinha percebido.